# How to get a pdf printout in landscape format?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, seam, itext, printer-properties

This is with reference to this thread [How to make a pdf printout occupy the entire A4 page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673938/how-to-make-a-pdf-printout-occupy-the-entire-a4-page).

I am able to bring all the content into a single page, but even if I set the printer preferences to landscape format, it doesn't print it.

What could be the problem?

Comment: It's helpful if you can add a code sample as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you setting the orientation attribute of the  tag?  That attribute controls the orientation of the page, and you should set it to landscape.

From the [Seam documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.2.Final/reference/en-US/html_single/#itext)

> orientation — The orientation of the
>   page. Valid values are portrait and
>   landscape. In landscape mode, the
>   height and width page size values are
>   reversed.